# SQL Server Transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have 2 sql server statements .

```
Delete from hello where id=1

Insert into hello name,age 
select name ,age from welcome
```

If either of one fails.No Deletion or Insertion should be done.

I tried with transaction

```
Begin Tran

    Delete from hello where id=1

    Insert into hello (name,age) 
    select name ,age from welcome


Commit Tran
```

But if either one is gone wrong .Other one is committed.Am i missing something.

```
2 delete statements

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;


  delete from hello where id=1

  delete from hello where id=19  // here id=19 doesn't exist

    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Here id=19 doesn't exists so it should rollback but it is deleting id=1. It is committed instead of rollback.What should i do in this Scenerio..

Comment: See [Basic template for Transactions in sqlserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290668/basic-template-for-transactions-in-sqlserver)

Comment: Thanks for Useful information Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if either one is gone wrong .Other one is committed.Am i missing
>   something.

Yes, you are missing error handling.  Depending on the error, T-SQL batches may continue following an error and execute subsequent statements, including the commit.  Below is a structured error handling example to avoid this.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;

    DELETE FROM hello WHERE id=1;

    INSERT INTO hello (name,age) 
    SELECT name ,age FROM welcome;

    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have additional business rules that are not SQL Server errors, you can detect the condition in the T-SQL code and raise an error to invoke the CATCH block and rollback:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;

    DELETE FROM hello WHERE id=1;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Row not found', 16, 1);
    END;

    INSERT INTO hello (name,age) 
    SELECT name ,age FROM welcome;

    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Yes I missed Error handling..Thanks Dan

Comment: Hi when i tried with 2 delete statements inside error handling it is committed..I have edited it in my question..What should i do in this scenerio..

Comment: @havin, no rows deleted/updated is not technically an error but perhaps a business rule violation.  In that case, you need to detect the error condition in the code and raise the error.  I'll extend my answer to include this.