# Determine any missed updates in batch process

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm synchronizing two applications and ERP and CRM. We have one process that runs in real time with triggers and second method that runs as a batch. When I run the batch I need to check for any missed records in the event that a batch didn't run. I've used a process yes/no column at times. But need a way to determine how to check that the insert completed and then set the processed column to yes. It must be something like if insert completes then set processed column to Y. And is it better to use a cursor and go one insert at a time or run the insert statement for the batch table?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT CONTACTS ON
INSERT INTO CONTACTS
                         (CODE, ID, CODE_ID, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME, ADDR, DECEASED_FLAG, CREATEDATE, CREATETIME, IDSeq)
SELECT        CC.CODE, CC.ID, CC.CODE_ID, CC.FIRSTNAME, CC.MIDDLENAME, CC.LASTNAME, CC.CREATE_DATE, CC.CREATE_TIME, CC.IDSeq
FROM            CONTACTSCHANGES AS CC INNER JOIN
                         CONTACTS AS C ON CC.ID = C.ID
SET IDENTITY_INSERT CONTACTS OFF


UPDATE       CONTACTSCHANGES
SET                Processed = N'Y'
```

Comment: You might want to make this into a Transaction with a check at the end that can rollback changes if the insert didn't complete successfully.  I would never suggest using cursors ever unless you have some Dynamic SQL to run.  If you need to update or insert a bunch of data, do it in transaction batches of 10,000 rows or something before checking if it completed successfully.  Here's some info on transactions.  I'm sorry I'm still kind of confused what you're trying to do. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql

Comment: we have customers in the crm, so when the names and address are updated we're going to change them in the erp, i have a trigger on the costumer contacts table and when the customer status is changed it will ad the customer name record to the contactschanges table. on a period of 15 minutes we will insert new customers or update customers in the erp contacts. what we have si that sometimes the update doesn't run so we need to check for any missed update batch and update it, so we want to keep the changes in the contactschanges to make sure none are missed

Comment: what sql statements do i look for to determine if the batch completes, it must be something like if begin tansaction update/or insert..., commit is true, then update processed column to Y, if false, then do nothing and the next time we try we still have the changed records in the contactschanges table so we have another chance to do it

Comment: use a transaction structure similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290668/basic-template-for-transactions-in-sqlserver   you can tell if the transaction ran successfully by maybe inserting a line into a logging table that can be queried.

Comment: what we need to do is make sure that the records are posted from the crm to the erp, we have two processes that can fail, 1. the sql agent doesn't execute the stored procedure that inserts the records, or 2. there is some error inserting the records and it doesn't complete. for error 2 it looks like i would use the commit rollback and try again. for error 1 what i could think of is this table of records for the batch with the processed column yes or no. is there a better way to do it?